# Why would PHP's empty() function not work as expected with $this->data in CakePHP 2?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

*To alleviate some confusion, I've completely re-written this question.*

---

Here is the controller:

```
<?php
class StaffController extends AppController{
    function test(){
        $this->data = $this->Staff->find( 'list' );
    }
}
```

Here is the *entire* view:

```
<pre>
Count: <?php echo count( $this->data ) . "\n"; ?>
Empty: <?php echo ( empty( $this->data ) ? 'true' : 'false' ) . "\n"; ?>
Count: <?php echo count( $this->data ) . "\n"; ?>
<?php var_dump( $this->data ) ?>
</pre>
```

Here is the rendered output:

```
Count: 2
Empty: true
Count: 2
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(12) "Mock Staff 1"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "Mock Staff 2"
}
```

Why would `empty()` return True when both `count()` and `debug()` show that a non-empty value has been assigned?

Is this a CakePHP bug?  A PHP bug?  ???

If I use another variable instead of $this->data :

```
function test(){
    $this->set( 'data', $this->Staff->find( 'list' ) );
}
```

And the view:

```
<pre>
Count: <?php echo count( $data ) . "\n"; ?>
Empty: <?php echo ( empty( $data ) ? 'true' : 'false' ) . "\n"; ?>
Count: <?php echo count( $data ) . "\n"; ?>
<?php var_dump( $data ) ?>
</pre>
```

it works as expected:

```
Count: 2
Empty: false
Count: 2
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(12) "Mock Staff 1"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "Mock Staff 2"
}
```

Any takers?

Comment: Did you try "$this->request->data"?

Comment: Where are you echoing / debugging the $this->data array (controller or model). If in the controller?  Does your code look exactly like in this example; theres no where that $this->data gets overwritten between echoing your count and testing for emptiness? Are you using PHP 5.3 or higher?

Comment: @ScottHarwell The above echoing/debugging is in the view.  The debug code tested for the purpose of this question is exactly as typed above -- no chance for anything to get rewritten in between -- a foreach loop that iterates over $this->data *after* the `empty()` test is able to display all the elements of the array.  PHP 5.3.6.

Comment: @ScottHarwell The above echoing/debugging is in the view.  The debug code tested for the purpose of this question is exactly as typed above -- no chance for anything to get rewritten in between -- a foreach loop that iterates over $this->data *after* the `empty()` test is able to display all the elements of the array.  PHP 5.3.6.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening, but you probably shouldn't be assigning $this->data in your view.  Rather assign a new variable the data from your find and work with it that way.  Like $data = $this->Model->findById(1);

Comment: @ScottHarwell Good point about using another variable name.  Assigning the data to another variable name corrects the symptoms, however I'm still boggled as to why `empty` isn't working with $this->data while other functions work just fine...

Comment: I think because the view uses $this->data and is probably reassigning the variable. But I can't be sure without seeing the whole function.

Comment: @ScottHarwell Updated the question to include full controllers & views.  I can work around it, but I'm curious as to why it's happening.

Comment: @JohnWatson's answer below explains why you shouldn't assign data to $this->data in your controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->data` is special in Cake views. When you access `$this->data` in a view, you actually end up calling the magic method `View::__get()`, and `empty()` doesn't work with methods or functions--it only works with variables. As you've found, the correct way to pass data to a view is by using `$this->set()` in your controller. Just to clarify, `$this` in the view is a different object than `$this` in your controller.

Comment: I think he was setting $this->data in his controller, not view.  I haven't had time to look at the AppController code to see exactly why it happening though.  However, would you agree that best practice would be to avoid setting $this->data outside of a model anyway?

Comment: Yes, I know. He SETs $this->data in the controller but is accessing $this->data in the view. And they're different variables. $this in the View is an instance of View and $this in the controller is an instance of the controller. And yes I agree you should avoid using $this->data because it's often used internally by the object as in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that $this->data is inaccessible? (odd since you're in the class itself), in which case:

> [When using empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) on inaccessible object properties, the __isset overloading method will be called, if declared.

Either way, I would add a function to the class, something like $this->hasData() and use that instead. Have hasData return whether $this->data has elements.

Comment: Updated the question to address this specifically.  For testing purposes related to this question I have `count($this->data)` followed immediately by `empty($this->data)` and `count` is returning "2" while empty is returning True.  If $this->data is inaccessible, `count` wouldn't work either.